# screen on/off broadcast events in Firefox OS

Tags: firefox-os

In Android, we can use "Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF" and "Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON" to receive the screen on/off broadcast events.
But in firefox OS, does the same way to receive the screen on/off broadcast events??

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the `visibilitychange` event.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/visibilitychange